# Java script associated with the PDF document not working in a web page

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

I am embedding the PDF in a web page using java script.

```
var addEmbededPdf = function() {
    var pdfContainer = document.getElementById('pdfContainer');
    pdfContainer.innerHTML = '<embed src="' + $scope.pdfpath + '" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="600px"></embed>';
  };
```

**Two things here.**

1. Adding the PDF through the Java script
2. The PDF being added also has java script associated with the
   document

The generated PDF has some back end Java script which works perfectly when document is opened through the Acrobat/Adobe reader.

When I the pdf in my web page the java script associated with the PDF is not working.

I think

Is there any way to change so that Java script associated with my PDF works fine.

Comment: Is acrobat's browser plugin loading the pdf, or is some other program's plugin loading it? It might be that whichever app's plugin that is doing the pdf loading disables javascript, this maybe an entirely client side setting that cannot be changed.

Comment: @PatrickEvans. Thanks for response. Can we set it to load plugin which is capable of executing the java script

Comment: I believe which plugin does the loading is a purely client side browser setting, for instance to get chrome to not use its built-in pdf reader you have to disable it in `chrome:plugins`

Answer (score 0):

i think javascript cannot run directly from pdf via web browser, you must use pdf reader that support javascript

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using the embed tag and not an iframe? Use the iframe tag and point its src to the pdf and you should be fine